# Rewriting data inside a list by enum values

Tags: python, list, enums

Let's say i have an enum that looks like this:

```
class MyEnum(str, Enum):
    A = 'atk'
    C = 'ccc'
    B = 'break'
```

And a list looking like so:

```
list = ['A', 123, 'B', 44, 2, 'C']
```

How do i make it that the A B and C in array are changed by its Enum values and look something like that?

```
list = ['atk', 123, 'break', 44, 2, 'ccc']
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try whether each list element is an enum value (see, e.g., [How to test if an Enum member with a certain name exists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29795488/how-to-test-if-an-enum-member-with-a-certain-name-exists)) and just replace the value in this case:

```py
def replace(x):
    try:
        return MyEnum[x].value
    except KeyError:
        return x
        
list = [replace(x) for x in list]
```

Try it online [here](https://www.online-python.com/QwXlD9gao3).

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
from enum import Enum


class MyEnum(str, Enum):
    A = "atk"
    C = "ccc"
    B = "break"


lst = ["A", 123, "B", 44, 2, "C"]

lst = [MyEnum[v].value if v in MyEnum.__members__ else v for v in lst]

print(lst)
```

Prints:

```py
['atk', 123, 'break', 44, 2, 'ccc']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply achieve this by using [`for...in`](https://wiki.python.org/moin/ForLoop) loop to iterate the `list` and then based on the type checking you can assign the `enum` value at that list index.

```
from enum import Enum

class MyEnum(str, Enum):
    A = 'atk'
    C = 'ccc'
    B = 'break'

list = ['A', 123, 'B', 44, 2, 'C'];

for x in list:
    elIndex = list.index(x)
    if((type(x) is str) and (x in [n.name for n in MyEnum])):
        list[elIndex] = MyEnum[x].value
    else:
        list[elIndex] = x

print(list)
```